# how to check and validate the url of a previous visit to our page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, static-pages

I have a static page in the form of a puzzle, I want to use the argument "if else" so that my page can be viewed if the url of my page is clicked from the site I want. For example, simple.

if my result page is visited through this site.

https://example.com

so
https://example.com/result
can be seen.

however, if my page is visited through this site

https://example-2.com

or not through example.com site, or visit the example.com/result link directly without going through the https://example.com

so
https://example.com/result
Not showing anything.

Can I implement a system like this on my static page using only arguments if else jquery?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```js
document.referrer
```

`The Document.referrer property returns the URI of the page that linked to this page`.[(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)

you can do something like this

```js
if (document.referrer != ""){
    if (new URLPattern(document.referrer).hostname === new URLPattern(window.location.origin).hostname){
        //show result 
    }
}
```